# Effective way to Replace if and elif in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have,

```
                if str1 in bigger_str or str2 in bigger_str:
                    return X
                elif str3 in bigger_str or str4 in bigger_str:
                    return Y
                else:
                    return Z
```

Is this effective or is there more effective way of executing and in terms of LOC

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a shorter version.
But in this specific case, where each condition results in a `return` statement, you could remove the last `else` like so:

```
                if str1 in bigger_str or str2 in bigger_str:
                    return X
                elif str3 in bigger_str or str4 in bigger_str:
                    return Y
                return Z
```

And if you are really only interested in the number of LOC, you can also remove the line breaks:

```
                if str1 in bigger_str or str2 in bigger_str: return X;
                elif str3 in bigger_str or str4 in bigger_str: return Y;
                return Z
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative for switch case in python is something like this

```
def run(string x):
    return {
      str1:x,
      str2:x,
    }.[x]
```

Switch case is a good alternative for if else but python does not have switch case.